# Problem with GCC compiler

Tags: string, c

I am using Arch Linux and when I am compiling and running the following C code,

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include<string.h>

int main(void) {
    char s1[]="Hello";
    char s2[]="World";

    strcat(s1,s2);
    int s2_len=strlen(s2);

    printf("s1 = %s, s2 = %s and length of s2 = %d.\n", s1, s2, s2_len);

    return 0;
}
```

I am getting the output:

```
s1 = HelloWorld, s2 = orld and length of s2 = 4.
```

Although the output shoud be `s1 = HelloWorld, s2 = World and length of s2 = 5.` and it is the output when I am using some online IDE.

Can somebody explain me why is this happening?

Comment: You are overflowing your `s1` causing undefined behavior. The problem is with your code and not the compiler (and this should be your assumption *always*. The cases where compiler is wrong are extremely rare).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
char s1[]="Hello";
char s2[]="World";

strcat(s1,s2);
```

The variable declarations allocate memory for 5 characters each, plus the terminating NUL byte. Your `strcat` call writes past that space, which produces undefined results.

In this case, the memory layout is probably something like this

```
0 1 2 3 4  5 6 7 8 9 10 11
H e l l o \0 W o r l  d \0
^            ^
s1           s2
```

After the `strcat`, the result is:

```
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11
H e l l o W o r l d \0 \0
^           ^
s1          s2
```

Which gives the result you see. Note that there could be other possible results, the program could e.g. crash at the `strcat` call.